# How to remove the line between Header and ContentPresenter when TabControl.TabItem has fixed value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

[image: TabStripPlacement difference with different header size.]

Look at the difference if I replace this code:

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="Example"/>
    </TabControl>
```

with this one:

```
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem Header="Example" Width="57" />
    </TabControl>
```

In the second case, how can I avoid the drawing of the vertical line between Header and ContentPresenter of the TabControl.TabItem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `HeaderTemplate` instead and put the fixed size within the `DataTemplate`.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem Header="Example">
        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Example" TextAlignment="Center" Width="57" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```